# Sort based on column in child table using GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a table called employee and child table address.

Now I want to get a list of employees sort by address1 in address table using GORM.

```
Employee.findAllByName(name, [max: maxRecords, offset: 100,sort: Address.address1, order: desc])
```

the above statement is not working, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would look at this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder  Looks like you might be able to define a default sorting in the Employee Mapping.

Comment: The `sort` param must be the name of the field to sort by. You should really use a criteria or HQL if you plan to sort by properties inside other tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) query like so...

```
def c = Employee.createCriteria()
def results = c.list (max: maxRecords, offset: 100) {
    eq("name", name)
    address {
        order("addres1", "desc")
    }

}
```

This works for me!

**Another option** is to add a default sort order like so...

```
class Address{
    …
    static mapping = {
        sort address1:"desc"
    }
}
```

**However**, I always prefer to do things as an 'as-needed' basis rather than define that sorting be done every time even when it may not be needed.  U pick.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Michael, but will it work if I pass sort order dynamically from the request?

Comment: sure... order("address1", "${params.sortOrder}")

Comment: Your first method does not work. I have verified i with a test