# Sort GORM query result by a column of a foreign key

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a foreign key relationship that is fully mapped in Grails, let say:

```
class Hero {
    Long id
    String name
    Long experience

    Pet pet
    .....
}

class Pet {
    Long id
    String name
    Long ownerId
    .....
}
```

Lets say I want to query all `Hero` who named their `Pet` something like *"Hiccup"*. So I'll perform a query to the `Hero` class:

```
def matching = Hero.findAll {
    ilike('pet.name', '%Hiccup%')
}
```

And it worked! The problem is how can I sort the returned `List` by the `Pet`'s `Name` column? I've tried:

```
def matching = Hero.findAll {
    ilike('pet.name', '%Hiccup%')
    orderBy('pet.name', 'asc')
}
```

But it returns an error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException:
could not resolve property: pet.name of: Hero
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can use criteria query like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618345/sort-based-on-column-in-child-table-using-gorm

Comment: It used to be `pet{orderBy('name', 'asc')}`

Comment: @defectus What do you meant by _"it used to be"_? BTW this is on Grails 2.3

Comment: Grails 2.5. Nested objects were referred to in closures like (`a{b{c{eq('propertyOfC', 'someValue')}}}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
def matching = Hero.withCriteria {
    pet {
       ilike('name', '%Hiccup%')
       orderBy('name', 'asc')
    }
}
```

or the other way around:

```
def matching = Pet.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property('hero')
    }
    ilike('name', '%Hiccup%')
    orderBy('name', 'asc')
}
```

But this only works when you declare the pet <--> hero relationship with grails command. I dont know if this is a one-to-one / one-to-many

It should be like this (one-to-one):

```
class Hero {
    Long id
    String name
    Long experience

    static hasOne = [pet:Pet]
    .....
}

class Pet {
    Long id
    String name
    Long ownerId
    .....

    static belongsTo = [hero:Hero]
}
```